# ECONNREFUSED on datagram Unix socket

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, unix-socket

What are the possible reasons for ECONNREFUSED when sending over a connectionless datagram Unix socket?

Also any advice on how to debug this is welcomed as this problem is reproducible.

I get the error regardless if `sendto()`or `sendmsg()` is used.

```
if ((sock = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}
unlink("/tmp/serv");
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;    

strncpy(&addr.sun_path[0], "/tmp/serv", sizeof(addr.sun_path));

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}

sockaddr_un from;
int fromlen = sizeof(from);
if (recvfrom(sock, &i, sizeof(i),0,(sockaddr*)&from,(socklen_t*)&fromlen) < 0 )
{
    //some error handling code
}

printf("from.sun_family=%d, from.sun_path=%s",from.sun_family,from.sun_path); // this prints, as expected "from.sun_family=1, from.sun_path=/tmp/client"
strncpy(&addr.sun_path[0], "/tmp/client", sizeof(addr.sun_path));
sendto(sock,"abc",3,0,(sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); //this fails with ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: Err, the target socket doesn't exist?

Comment: It exists. I edited the code in the question to show that the client sends a message and `recvfrom` works as expected. The client app is stuck in a `recv()` ( I can breakpoint there )

Comment: @George which call in your code here is giving you ECONNREFUSED ?

Comment: @nos sendto(sock,"abc",3,0,(sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

Comment: @George And what does the client do ? The error you're getting here suggest your client is not alive and serving /tmp/client

Comment: @nos The client is alive and is waiting in `recv()`

Comment: @George Well, something is going on (e.g. you're starting multiple copies of the client or server, there's a bug somewhere, someething crashed etc.) otherwise you wouldn't get the error that you're getting- which you get when trying to send to a socket that's dead - see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854212/domain-socket-sendto-encounter-errno-111-connection-refused) for a few tips on how to debug it. I suggest you post your client code too.

Comment: Post minimal compilable and runnable client and server. You may well find the bug while preparing these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 7 unix`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

> **ECONNREFUSED**
>   The remote address specified by connect(2) was not  a  listening socket. *This error can also occur if the target filename is not a socket.*

In Linux, `sendto` on Unix socket [does the following](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/unix/af_unix.c#L1548):

```
1548         if (sock_flag(other, SOCK_DEAD)) {
1549                 /*
1550                  *      Check with 1003.1g - what should
1551                  *      datagram error
1552                  */
1553                 unix_state_unlock(other);
1554                 sock_put(other);
1555 
1556                 err = 0;
1557                 unix_state_lock(sk);
1558                 if (unix_peer(sk) == other) {
1559                         unix_peer(sk) = NULL;
1560                         unix_state_unlock(sk);
1561 
1562                         unix_dgram_disconnected(sk, other);
1563                         sock_put(other);
1564                         err = -ECONNREFUSED;
1565                 } else {
1566                         unix_state_unlock(sk);
1567                 }
1568 
1569                 other = NULL;
1570                 if (err)
1571                         goto out_free;
1572                 goto restart;
1573         }
```

In other words, there is no reader on the other end of the socket you send to, or the socket does not longer exist in the filesystem.

Comment: Well, I have a socket on the other side ( client side ), the bind worked fine. I can even send stuff from client and receive with recvfrom on server.

Comment: @George Your client may have terminated after sending.

Comment: I'm afraid not, the client has some very simple code, after it sends with `sendto()` it waits in `recv()`.

Comment: As I said, the problem is 100% reproducible so I removed any unnecessary code. That `sendto()` really sends "abc". On client side I really have just a `sendto()` a `setsockopt()` setting a 5sec timeout and a `recv()`.

Comment: Indeed, if I reinitialize the socket on client side, everything works as expected. I am puzzled now as nothing seems to indicate that the client socket is closed. If I close(socket) I don't get EBADF, the /tmp/client exists in the filesystem, I can send using that socket and the other side gets it's address if I use recvfrom. My question is: is there any way to find out if the socket is opened?

Comment: @George The correct way would be to make sure the socket is not closed, especially if it is simple code as you mentioned. Run your client under gdb, set a breakpoint on `close` and `shutdown` and see what calls it with your socket.